# How do I blur an element with scroll, until it's blurred to a certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

How do I blur an image as the user scrolls down the page, and then stop when it gets to **blur(15px)**? I don't want the image to get so blurry that it takes over the whole screen.

Here's what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<img class="boop" src="images/boop.jpg" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var distanceScrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.boop').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur('+distanceScrolled/30+'px)');
});
```

I've been googling how to set a maximum value for the distanceScrolled variable or the CSS filter and can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compute the min of the amount scrolled and 15 in the blur function. Like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var distanceScrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.boop').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(' + Math.min(distanceScrolled/30, 15) + 'px)');
});
```

Then it will stop at `15px`.

Comment: Even simpler than I'd hoped. Thanks!